# Symbol of interior and closure in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

What is code of this line below related to the interior and the closure of A in D?  Thank you 
[image]

Comment: `\mathring{A}` and `\overline{A}`

Comment: Better `\newcommand*\interior[1]{\mathring{#1}}` and `\newcommand*\closure[1]{\overline{#1}}` (or `\bar{#1}`) and then use `\interior{A}` and `\closure{A}`.

Comment: @Manuel Care to write up an answer to get this off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 4):

```
\newcommand*\interior[1]{\mathring{#1}}
\newcommand*\closure[1]{\overline{#1}} % (or \bar{#1})
```

and then use `\interior{A}` and `\closure{A}`.